# Android code to tick the check on listview row onclick

Tags: android

Using this code `checkBox` clicking work properly.

How to check the `CheckBox` of `ListView` when item clicked?

I have a `ListView` with `CheckBox`, `TextView`.How to do this?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {

        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_orgmemberlist_item,
                null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.selected = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final MemberClass data = mAllitems.get(position);

    if (data != null) {
        holder.name.setText(data.getMmembers_first_name());
        holder.selected.setChecked(data.isSelected());
        holder.selected.setTag(data);
    }

    holder.selected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;

             MemberClass _state = (MemberClass) cb.getTag();            
            _state.setSelected(cb.isChecked());         

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole code of your adapter class

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor make an arraylist of same size as of your mAllitems like:

```
ArrayList<Boolean> isCheckedItem = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ;i < mAllitems.size(); i++){
            isCheckedItem.set(i, false);
        }
```

After this in getView() methid where you checking data!=null put this code:

```
if(isCheckedItem.get(position)){
            holder.selected.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            holder.selected.setChecked(false);
        }
```

remove holder.selected.setOnClickListener() method and add  holder.selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener() method :

```
holder.selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int position = (int)buttonView.getTag();
                if(isChecked){
                    isCheckedItem = true;
                }else{
                    isCheckedItem = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set onItemClickListener to your listview and in that access your CheckBox and then you can make it checked/unchecked. Like this :

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long   id) {

View v;

int count = parent.getChildCount();

parent.requestChildFocus(v, view);  

        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            v =parent.getChildAt(i);         
                if(v instanceof CheckBox){
                final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                cb.setChecked(true);
                }   
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this may help you.